# How can i remove (not set) in google analytics path exploration with react native?

Tags: react-native, google-analytics

I implemented Google analytics in the React native app.

The code to log the screen is as follows.

```
<NavigationContainer
                linking={linking}
                ref={(navigationRef) =>
                  (this.navigationRef = navigationRef)
                }
                onReady={() => {
                  this.routeNameRef =
                    this.navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name;

                  // first log in init
                  Analytics.logScreenView({
                    screen_name: this.routeNameRef,
                    screen_class: this.routeNameRef,
                  });
                }}
                onStateChange={async () => {
                  const previousRouteName = this.routeNameRef;
                  const currentRoute = this.navigationRef.getCurrentRoute();
                  const currentRouteName = currentRoute.name;
                  const currentScreenName =
                    (currentRoute.params &&
                      currentRoute.params.screenName) ||
                    currentRouteName;

                  if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
                    await Analytics.logScreenView({
                      screen_name: currentScreenName,
                      screen_class: currentRouteName,
                    });
                  }

                  // Save the current route name for later comparision
                  this.routeNameRef = currentRouteName;
                }}
              >
```

After the app was released, I tried to determine which page the user was browsing in Google Analytics path exploration.

But when i set STARTING POINT to "first_open"(the first time a user launches an app after installing or re-installing it), **STEP 1's page title and screen name is set to (not set)**

[image]

What is wrong with this? What am i doing wrong?
and **step2 has 39 event count, but step3 has 35 event count.
where is 4 event count? 4 user exited app?**

Is there something wrong with the way I look at the report?
How exactly is it to access the app and see which page the user has moved to?
Debugging did not detect that screen name was not set.

Comment: you're missing a step. Show a screenshot of the network requests sent to GA. Use "collect" as a filter.

Comment: @BNazaruk Thank you for your advice. But i checked screen name in console.log and realtime report in ga dashboard. I can't understand what you said. What is missing step meaning? Sorry for my knowledge...

Comment: uh, sorry, I missed the native part of react. You want to inspect the actual network requests you're sending to GA. Through fiddler, charles or, I believe, Flipper would do the trick for React Native a lot better.

Comment: @BNazaruk I can't find network request :( I tried to check through mitmproxy, but i found only "https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog" requests.

there is no "collect" like,, BUT in GA4 realtime dashboard, there is screen name correctly.